# Get view name programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-view

I am doing a small library to encapsulate adapters functionality and I need get the name of a view programmatically. For example:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/**ivPerson**"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>
```

Now, in the code I have the view (ImageView) and I need obtain the name of the view --> ivPerson. I can obtain the id with view.getId() but that's not what I need.

It is possible?

I tried with this:

```
String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
```

But not work.

Comment: Such name-to-id mapping resides in the generated R file. So, such reverse lookup may be possible with reflection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it by setting tag as the id i.e `android:tag="ivPerson"`
 and use `String name = view.getTag().toString()` to get the name of the tag

Comment: But this will cause issues when he needs the tag for other purposes.

Comment: It is a good idea and work fine. I`m continue searching other way 
without using the tag field. Thanks!!

Answer (score 14):

You can use `getResourceName(...)` instead.

```
String fullName = getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
```

But there is a some problem. This method will give you a full path of view like: `"com.google:id/ivPerson"`

Anyway, you can use this trick to get only name of a view:

```
String fullName = getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
String name = fullName.substring(fullName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Now `name` will be exactly `"ivPerson"`

Answer (score 9):

For the `View v` get its name as follows:

```
String name = (v.getId() == View.NO_ID) ? "" :
    v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()).split(":id/")[1];
```

If the view `v` has no name, then the `name` is an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get `ivPerson` id using `getId()` or any other method, however you can get it by setting tag value as mentioned in rahul's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34528164/3134215)

set tag in xml :

```
android:tag="ivPerson"
```

fetch it in your activity

```
view.getTag().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like this:

```
    for(Field field : R.id.class.getFields()) {
        try {
            if(field.getInt(null) == R.id.helloTV) {
                Toast.makeText(this, field.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### Pros:

- No need for manually setting the tag. So you may use the tag for other purposes.

### Cons:

- Slower due to reflection.

Comment: It`s OK but this I am using within an adapter so that maybe by introducing a loop behavior worsens. It is a good idea. I'll try both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
String name = ((view != null) && (view.getId() != View.NO_ID)) ? getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId()) : "";
```